# Count inserts, deletes and updates in a PowerCenter session

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

Is there a way in PowerCenter 9.1 to get the number of inserts, deletes and updates after an execution of a session? I can see the data on the log but I would like to see it in a more ordered fashion in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know requires building the mapping appropriately. You need to have 3 separate instances of the target and use a router to redirect the rows to either `TARGET_insert` or `TARGET_update` or `TARGET_delete`. Workflow Monitor will then show a separate row for the inserted, updated and deleted rows.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways,
1. You can use $tgtsuccessrows / $TgtFailedRows and assign it to workflow variable
2. Expression transformation can be used with a variable port to keep track of insert/update/delete
3. You can even query OPB_SESSLOG  in second stream to get row count inside same session.

Not sure if PowerCenter 9.1 offers a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can design your mapping to populate a Audit table to track the number of insert/update/delete's

You can download a sample implementation from Informatica Marketplace block titled "PC Mapping : Custom Audit Table"

https://community.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_custom_audit_table

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways like you can create a assignment task attach this assignment task just after you session once the session complete its run the assignment task will pass on the session stats from session to the workflow variable defined at workflow level, sessions stats like $session.status,$session.rowcount etc and now create a worklet having a mapping included in it, pass the session stats captured at workflow level to the newly created worklet and from worklet to the mapping, now once the stats are available at mapping level in the mapping scan these stats (using a SQL or EXP transformation) and then write these stats to the AUDIT table ... attach the combination of assignment task and worklet after each session and it will start capturing the stats of each session after the session completes it run....